# PHP Array Slice understanding

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

**Array**

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
  ...
)
[41] => Array (
  [name] => London 
  [company] => nhyt6t
  [top25_1] => 8.75912088
)
[42] => Array (
  [name] => Manchester
  [company] => gtr4rf
  [top25_1] => 6.56758398
)
  ...
[75] => Array (
  [name] => Leeds
  [company] => de3wsd6
  [top25_1] => 7.58675398
)
)
```

If my reading and understanding of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php is correct, then the following should return just those within the array with an index of between 40 and 65.

```
$array = array_slice($array, 40, 65);
```

However, in practise, what this does is remove Indexes `0` through `39` but leaves everything else.

Can anyone explained where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 40, 65 - 40);
```

So:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 40, 25);
```

We start slicing from 40 position and get 25 elements (ending on 40+25=65 position).

Comment: `65 - 40 + 1` if you want `65` to be included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Array slice chooses an offset and length, not a begin offset and end offset. It starts at the begin offset and chooses the next length elements. If your array has continuous indices (0,1,2,3,4...), then it will slice from `[offset -> offset + length)`

Comment: Must admit to struggling to get my head around the way this works.

Comment: My explanation, or the documentation?

Comment: Not your explanation - the documentation and concept!  LOL, sorry if it came across differently!